# Problems running pygame script

Tags: python, directory, pygame, anaconda, spyder

Currently trying to run a pygame script. The Script itself is fine however I think the installation is causing me some problems. I am using a mac and my script is located on my desktop. If I would like to load images on to the script I must place this in '/users/himansu' In addition I am using spyder (anaconda) when running this. I have tried terminal which keeps bringing up the error:

AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'

When I hit run in spyder it loads the pygame script however my keys are not moving the object on screen rather the cursor remains inside the spyder application.. This I know hasn't got anything to do with the code which is posted below:

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')


def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))


def game_loop():


    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0
    print(x_change)

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        #event handling loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                #one way to exit the loop
                gameExit = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        gameDisplay.fill(white)    
        car(x,y)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
game_loop()
pygame.quit() 
quit()
```

The code worked (the keys moved the object) when I was moving some files around however it is now back to normal. My working directory inside spyder is '/users/himansu'. I feel like if I can get this script running in terminal it may function. Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes spyder/anaconda needs dependencies for libraries installed in pip. Have you tried `conda install pygame` any chance?

Comment: @Pygasm thank you for your reply. Still facing the same issue sadly

Comment: Uh oh, definitely sounds like some internal stuff, you may need to do some virtual enviroment tweaking.

Comment: I have tried this command in terminal also: conda install -c cogsci pygame. I am now getting this error: UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pygame
  - xlwt
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package. any ideas? thank you

Comment: Try removing pygame in pip and conda, and reinstall only with conda. Maybe its getting confused with conflicting packages in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine i ran it and it worked. Try reinstalling pygame or adding sys to the import

```
import pygame, sys, os
```

direct download link ----> http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi